# Challenging Marginal Probability Question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've been stuck on this question for some time now - While I can derive the marginal density of X simply from the uniform distribution, I am at a loss for how the marginal density for Y and the joint density may be derived. Any suggestions?

John wakes 6 AM each morning and then lies in bed for up to 3 hours. After getting up he takes one hour to get ready for work. After that, John likes to play computer games until he goes to work. However he never leaves after 11 AM. For the 3 hours he lies in bed, John is equally likely to get up at any time within that timeframe (uniformly distributed). Also, from the from the time he begins playing computer games and 11 AM, John is equally likely to go to work at any time during that timeframe.

Suppose X is the time John lies in bed, and Y the number of hours from waking to the moment he left home. Find the following:

a. Determine the marginal density of X.

b. Determine the marginal density of Y .

c. Determine the f(y, x).

d. Determine the f(y|x).

**Update 1:**

The marginal density for y I obtained, using the above information is:
f(y)=1/(4-x)
(sorry still havent figure out how to use LaTeX on this site!)

Answer (score 0):

Possible values taken by $X$ and $Y$ are in the shaded region:

[image]

The marginal density of $X$:

$$f_X(x) = \dfrac{1}{3}.$$

This is because it's a uniform distribution over $3$ hours duration. I presume you got this already.

You have $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{4-x}$ but $f_Y(y)$ cannot be a function of $x$. I think that this is the conditional density of $Y$ given $X$ rather than the marginal density: once $X$ is given, $Y$ has uniform distribution over an interval of length $4-X$. That is,

$$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{1}{4-x}.$$

We can now find the joint probability density of $X$ and $Y$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{X,Y}(x,y) &=& f_{Y|X}(y|x)\,f_X(x) \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{4-x}\cdot\dfrac{1}{3} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{12-3x}.
\end{eqnarray*}

We now find the marginal density of $Y$. We must do it in two pieces because the limits of integration for $x$ depends on the value of $y$. Firstly, for $0 \lt y \lt 1$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_Y(y) &=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\; dx \\
&& \\
&=& \int_{0}^{3} \dfrac{1}{12-3x}\; dx \\
&& \\
&=& -\dfrac{1}{3} \bigg[\ln{(4-x)}\bigg]_0^3 \\
&& \\
&=& \frac{2}{3} \ln{2}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
For $1 \lt y \lt 4$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_Y(y) &=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\; dx \\
&& \\
&=& \int_{0}^{4-y} \dfrac{1}{12-3x}\; dx \\
&& \\
&=& -\dfrac{1}{3} \bigg[\ln{(4-x)}\bigg]_0^{4-y} \\
&& \\
&=& -\frac{1}{3} \left(\ln{y} - 2\ln{2}\right) \\
&& \\
&=& \frac{2}{3} \ln{2} - \frac{1}{3} \ln{y}.
\end{eqnarray*}

So we have

$\qquad\qquad f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{3} \ln{2}, & \text{if $0 \lt y \lt 1$} \\
&& \\
\frac{2}{3} \ln{2} - \frac{1}{3} \ln{y}, & \text{if $1 \lt y \lt 4.$}
\end{cases}$